# Entity Framework and Scaffolded Item C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-services, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I´m making an Web Api using entity Frameworks and Scaffolded Item, this scaffolded Item crate the methods GET,PUT,POST,DELETE but the problem is how i can create a new custom method o get data from custom query in my controller.

Somebody help me please.

Comment: Why don't you just change the GET method to do what you want?

Comment: Well broadly speaking you write a method that takes the parameters you need, does the relevant query, returns the correct data and the set up a route to it.  I suggest you write your method and if you get stuck post a more specific question.

Comment: For example if i want to get data from 2 different tables. or 2 different models from entity framework.

Comment: Are you asking how to fetch the data or are you asking how to create a new method?

Comment: yes, i want to create a new method to get data from 2 tables.